# Overcoming multiple headers are not allowed in HTTP request

Tags: c#, .net, azure, http

I'm working on an Azure based app in .Net c#.
I have a function receiving a flag. when flag = false, I set the access condition to be AccessCondition.GenerateIfNotExistsCondition.
but ANYWAY I want to also add a condition of AccessCondition.GenerateIfMatchCondition to match the etags before updating.
when initiating an object of the access condition with both of them and approaching Azure with it, I'm getting an exception of **multiple headers not supported.**
does anybody knows how can I still get the wanted functionality?

this is how I initiate the AccessCondition object:

```
                var accessCondition = new AccessCondition()
            {
                IfNoneMatchETag = overwrite ? null : AccessCondition.GenerateIfNotExistsCondition().IfNoneMatchETag,
                IfMatchETag = _etag
            };
```

and then when calling

```
                await _blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(
                metadataContent,
                0,
                metadataContent.Length,
                accessCondition,
                null,
                null,
                cancellationToken);
```

I get the exception:
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException: Multiple condition headers are not supported.

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you please add your code that what you have tried so far .

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT added :)

Comment: Please also edit the question to include the full stack trace.

Comment: @RB.I added the exception explicitly, stack trace is super messy since I work with many packages and nugets